# Read txt file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, text-files

I have a trouble reading the **txt** file, which contains 10 columns and 2 lines of header, but the problem is that in the middle of the file the same header appears several times and `textread()` doesnt function. That's my file example:

#### file.txt

```
headerline1 aaaa
headerline2 111 123
20/12/2000 name1 name2 name3... name8 0
21/12/2000 name1 name2 name3... name8 0
22/12/2000 name1 name2 name3... name8 0
headerline1 aaaa
headerline2 111 123
25/12/2000 name1 name2 name3... name8 0
27/12/2000 name1 name2 name3... name8 0
...
```

and this is my code I tried:

```
[date, name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6, name7, name8, status] = ...
    textread('file.txt', '%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %d', 'headerlines',2);
```

It gives the error exactly at the row with the repeated header. Do you have any ideas how could I avoid those headers and read the complete file? The problem is that I have hundreds of these types of files, so I cant delete each time manually.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I'd suggest a perl script (or some other good text-processing language, like sed or awk, depending on what you're most familiar with) to preprocess the files and make copies without repeated headers.

Comment: I agree with Ben. textscan and textread both expect formatted data, so you'll need to preprocess them first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can first read the file line by line with `textscan` taking the whole line as a string. Then remove the headerlines, and process the rest

Here is an example:

```
%# read the whole file to a temporary cell array
fid = fopen(filename,'rt');
tmp = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');
fclose(fid);

%# remove the lines starting with headerline
tmp = tmp{1};
idx = cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x(1:10),'headerline'), tmp);
tmp(idx) = [];

%# split and concatenate the rest
result = regexp(tmp,' ','split');
result = cat(1,result{:});

%# delete temporary array (if you want)
clear tmp
```

Comment: Yup this is what I would do - keeps it all in MATLAB and allows you to adapt easily to different types of file and so on.

Comment: Wow! It works just perfectly! and seems much easier than I did with fgetl. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you do NOT want to use perl, awk or something like it to preprocess your data (which I actually could really understand), you could try to read your file line by line by using `fopen`, `fgetl` and `feof` (e.g. one example can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2858208/701049) and check for each line if it contains a header. If so, `continue` your loop. If not, process it by using something like `textscan` as you do now already.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I did:

Comment: fid=fopen('file.txt');
    while 1
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    if ~ischar(tline), break,end
    end
    fclose(fid)

Now there left just to save each line with textread. When I do it I will post the answer.

Comment: No it's actually correct, what you are doing :-) It's not that hard and if you don't understand something, just ask or look into the FAQs of the page :)