# How to Load a .txt file into an matrix of matlab

Tags: matlab, text-files, classification

Good day.
I would like to know how to load a .txt file in matlab. What I want is to work with text classification and guess the first thing to do is load devo my data in matlab .... but when I try to generate many files .my I just want an array containing my text.
Greetings and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple functions that do that: [`importdata`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html),[`textscan`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html),[`fopen`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html),[`dlmread`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) etc.
I do not understand much from your question, but begin by reading through these documentation pages and try them to see which works best for you.

Comment: I'm surprised I can't find a good enough duplicate for this lol. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng how about this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756029/read-from-a-text-file-and-load-it-into-a-matrix-in-matlab which is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470561/matlab-read-in-txt-file-into-array. Some of these questions are deep rooted.

Comment: @GameOfThrows - Yup.  One of the links is good.  I couldn't find the right one.  Thank you!