# Import text file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, import, matlab-guide

I have a tab delimited text file with suffix .RAW.

How can I load the data from the file into a matrix in MATLAB?

I have found [`readtable`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html), but it doesn't support files ending with suffix .RAW.

Do I really have to use `fread`, `fscanf`, etc. to simply load a text file into a matrix?

Comment: I also try to avoid `fread`,  and `fscanf` as much as possible :-) Check [`importdata`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) and [`dlmread`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab read in txt file into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470561/matlab-read-in-txt-file-into-array)

Comment: Did you try dlmread?

Comment: It seems `dlmread` works :-D but when I print the matrix, it factor out a number. Is this normal MATLAB behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`dlmread()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) function. It will read data from an ASCII text file into a matrix and let you define the delimiter yourself. The delimiter for tabs is `'\t'`.

```
>> M = dlmread('Data.raw', '\t')
M =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
```

Just for your information there is also the [`tdfread()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/tdfread.html) function but I do **not** recommend using it except in very specific cases. [`dlmread()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) is a much better option.

Answer (score -1):

.RAW is a generic file extention. You should know the format of your RAW file (especially if your file contains a combination of numbers, data structures etc). If it is a simple text file with a single 2D table, you can easily read it with `fscanf`, `fread`, `fgetl`, `fgets`, etc

Here is a simple example for a 2D table (matrix):
Let's assume that each row of your table is separated by a carriage return from its following rows. We can read each row by `fgetl()` and then extract numbers using `str2num()`.

```
fid=fopen('YourTextFile.RAW');
Data=[];
i = 0;
while 1
    i = i + 1;
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    if ~ischar(tline), break, end
    Data(i,:) = str2num(tline);
end
fclose(fid);
disp(Data)
```

For more complex data structure, the code should be changed.
For a 2D table (a special case) the above simple code can be easily exchanged by `dlmread()` function.

Comment: It is a simple text file (ASCII format with .raw file extension). Can you give a simple example of a script which loads the data in a matrix?

Comment: This is a comment and does not answer the question.

Comment: I do not agree. I've tested this code and it works. According to which reasoning you say that this code does not work in MATLAB?!!!