# Reading file in MATLAB having non CSV Data

Tags: matlab, file-io

Through a serial port I am getting data for X, Y and Z in a text file as follows:

```
X195Y207Z247
X195Y209Z248
X193Y207Z248
X195Y207Z248
X194Y207Z235
X193Y209Z248
X193Y220Z247
X193Y217Z237
X193Y220Z248
X193Y223Z248
X193Y227Z238
X193Y231Z248
```

i.e

> X=195, Y=207, Z=247

and so on...

I want to write a MATLAB script for reading this data into three vectors X, Y and Z.
A similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856417/reading-a-text-file-in-matlab-line-by-line) for a CSV file, but in my case data is not Comma separated.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
fid = fopen('data.dat','rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%*c %f %*c %f %*c %f', 'Delimiter','\n');
fclose(fid);

[X,Y,Z] = deal(C{:});
```

Result:

```
>> [X Y Z]
ans =
   195   207   247
   195   209   248
   193   207   248
   195   207   248
   194   207   235
   193   209   248
   193   220   247
   193   217   237
   193   220   248
   193   223   248
   193   227   238
   193   231   248
```

Answer (score 0):

```
values = sscanf(str2,'%*c%f%*c%f%*c%f',[1 Inf])
```

`X = values(1)` and so on...