# How to extract data from txt file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, file

For example
.txt file[pqfile.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3hN8AizIir6Yk03YmRFblZqcFk/view?usp=sharing)

```
255 20
40
1.0 1.3 1.7 1
7.1 7.2 7.3 0
1.1 1.2 1.4 1
6.1 8.2 9.1 0
40
1.0 1.3 1.7 1
7.1 7.2 7.3 0
1.1 1.2 1.4 1
6.1 8.2 9.1 0
40
```

I just need

```
1.0 1.3 1.7 
1.1 1.2 1.4 
1.0 1.3 1.7 
1.1 1.2 1.4
1.0 1.3 1.7 
1.1 1.2 1.4
```

and want to store this as struct
struct{1}
1.0 1.3 1.7 
1.1 1.2 1.4

struct{2}
1.0 1.3 1.7 
1.1 1.2 1.4

struct{3}
1.0 1.3 1.7 
1.1 1.2 1.4

Comment: very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856417/reading-a-text-file-in-matlab-line-by-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `textscan` to ignore the first two lines (by specifying `HeaderLines`) and then grab everything else, you can then index the result and only retrieve everyother row.

```
fid = fopen('pqfile.txt', 'r');

% Ignore the first two lines and read the rest of the data in as floats
alldata = textscan(fid, '%f', 'HeaderLines', 2);
alldata = reshape(alldata{1}, 4, []).';

% Only keep every other row and only the first 3 columns
data = alldata(1:2:end, 1:3);

%   1   1.3  1.7
% 1.1   1.2  1.4
```

**Update**

Once you have posted the actual data, here is a version that should operate properly on the chunks.

```
fid = fopen('pqfile.txt', 'r');
% Read and ignore the first line
fgetl(fid);

result = {};

% Loop until we hit the end of the file
while ~feof(fid)
    % Figure out how many lines to read
    nLines = fscanf(fid, '%d', 1);

    % Now read this many lines
    data = textscan(fid, '%f', nLines * 4); 

    % Now reshape this data
    data = reshape(data{1}, 4, []).';

    % Add the data to the overall data structure
    if ~isempty(data)
        result = cat(1, result, {data(1:2:end,1:3)});
    end
end
```

Comment: Can I save the answer in struct?

Comment: @Abhishek Like you want the entire matrix in the field of a struct?

Comment: Actually the file is very big full of floating point values except every 41st line which has value '40' needs to be excluded.

Comment: I thought of uploadingthe txt file to be more clearer on what I mean but I am unable to find the link

Actually it contains 9600 lines 
I need to
delete every 41st element
and
Alternate elements
Save the result in struct form of n '20*3' size struct

Comment: @Abhishek If you can update your original post showing example input/output that would be helpful

Comment: Yes Suever, I added attachment, Please let me know if I am clear now

Comment: @Abhishek Are you sure you want a struct or do you want a cell array? As you've shown it in your post it's a cell array

Comment: Could you please let me know whats the strategy you used to get rid of 40's decimal value?

Comment: @Abhishek I don't get rid of them, as they actually tell you how many lines there are until the *next* block. I read the `40` into `nLines` in the solution above and  use that to determine how many numbers to read with `textscan`.