# Matlab: For loop to go through 2 integrals for a list of values

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, integral, numerical-integration

I wrote some matlab code that loads in  3 text files to define r, t, and T variables (each file contains a vertical list of 763 numbers).

I need to run the first integral for each t and r value initially to derive "tr". I know I need to include a for loop for this so the code iterates over every t and r pair - I don't know how.

Secondly, I then take this new tr value and need to do 2 linear interpolations. The first linear interpolation will be using t and r to find a new tr_r and the second will be a linear interpolation between t and T to find a new tr_T.

The second integral will be fairly simple - again, I just don't know how to do a for loop to iterate over every new tr_r and tr_T value.

Suggestions? The complete code is below.

Thank you!

```
%Load Data
load ejradius.txt %loads text into workspace
fid = fopen( 'ejradius.txt');
data = textscan(fid, '%f');
fclose(fid);
r = data{1};

load ejtime.txt %loads text into workspace
fid = fopen( 'ejtime.txt');
data = textscan(fid, '%f');
fclose(fid);
t = data{1};

load ejtemp.txt %loads text into workspace
fid = fopen( 'ejtemp.txt');
data = textscan(fid, '%f');
fclose(fid);
T = data{1};

%Constants
h = 6.62607004e-34;
c = 2.9979e10;
k = 1.38064852e-23;

fun = @(x) t-((r)./c).*(1-cos(x))
tr = integral(fun,0,pi./2); 

tr_r = interp1(t,r,linear,tr); %linear interpolation to find new r given t,r, and tr
tr_T = interp1(t,T,linear,tr); %linear interpolation to find new T given t,T, and tr

fun2 = @(f) ((2.*pi.*h.*(f).^3)./c).*(1./exp((h.*(f))./(k.*(tr_T))-1));
f = integral(fun2,3.9e14,3.4e16);

fun3 = @(x) (tr_r.^2).*cos(x)
R = integral(fun3,0,pi./2);
R2 = R.*(2.*pi);
Lt = f.*R2;
```

Comment: I think the solution is similar to the answers of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2856417